# P2TR: Is pub key hashed in address?

Tags: hash, public-key, taproot, p2tr

Are the new Taproot addresses (SegWit v1) also a hash of the (potentially tweaked) public key, or is the public key directly encoded into the address, without hashing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Public keys are not hashed in Taproot (SegWit v1). The Taproot (Merkle) tree in the script path uses hashes but the Merkle root of this tree tweaks the unhashed public key (internal key) and the resulting tweaked public key is not hashed either. For more details on why see the [reference 2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki#cite_ref-2-0) in BIP 341.

Comment: Does that mean that there are roughly 2^256 possible Taproot addresses (eg pubkeys)?

Comment: Right, not quite 2^256 possible points on secp256k1 curve but pretty close https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114135/how-does-ecdsa-work-when-generating-the-public-key/