# How does ECDSA work when generating the public key?

Tags: wallet, private-key, public-key, ecdsa, secp256k1

I know the curve has formula `y^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b`. However, some websites are saying that `a=0` and `b=7` for secp256k1?

What is secp256k1? Is it the curve that is always used or does it generate the field in order to generate a new curve?

Answer (score 2):

> What is secp256k1, is it the curve that is always used

Indeed the elliptic curve used in Bitcoin is [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) which is the curve defined using `a=0` and `b=7` in your equation `mod p`. But other curves are used for other use cases (maybe other cryptocurrencies too, not sure).

> does it generate the field in order to generate a new curve.

No the curve stays the same. The field size `p` is implicitly defined by the curve. In secp256k1's case `p = 2^256 - 2^32 - 977` or `p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F` in hex and is prime.

The generator point G (on the curve) is (Gx, Gy) where

`Gx=0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798`

`Gy=0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8`

The curve order (how many points there are on the curve) of secp256k1 is:

`n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141`

For more details see Jimmy Song's first three chapters of his [book](https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin) Programming Bitcoin.

The question in the title asks about generating the public key. That is calculated by effectively multiplying the generator point G (coordinates) by the private key (scalar).